# How can I integrate filters defined using javax.ws.rs in to Spring WebClient?

Tags: spring, jax-rs, cxf, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I want to use apache.cxf filter **CreateSignatureInterceptor** in the spring WebClient but not able to do it.

The interceptor **CreateSignatureInterceptor** is found in the below dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-security-http-signature</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

The way I am creating the Spring WebClient is as below

```
private val webClient = WebClient.builder()
    .filter(logRequest())
    .clientConnector(JettyClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
    .baseUrl(baseUri)
    .build()

private fun logRequest(): ExchangeFilterFunction {
    return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor{
        log.info(it.url().toString())
       // --> how to add the existing apache filters
       // CreateSignatureInterceptor() 
        Mono.just(it)
    }
}
```

In this, we can create or add filters in spring WebClient like logRequest() but I am not sure how to integrate the existing defined filters.

As there are very less sources I find it hard to define the existing filters in the spring webclient.

Comment: you cannot directly use any "blocking" filter in the `Webclient` as the interfaces required do not match. If you are set on using that filter, you will need to write an adapter to make it compatible with non-blocking code.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelMcFadyen but is there any reference implementation on how the adapter should be implemented ??

Comment: [Reactor reference docs](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking) cover how to wrap a blocking call. With regards to adapting the types, I'm not too sure.